# how to use node.js module system on the clientside

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to use the CommonJS module system in a clientside javascript application. I chose nodejs as implementation but can't find any tutorial or docs on how to use nodejs clientside, ie without using `node application.js`

I included node.js like this in my html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node.js"></script>
```

Note that I didn't make nodejs on my local machine, I'm on Windows anyway (I'm aware of the Cygwin option). 
When I want to use the `require` function in my own javascript it says it's undefined.

```
var logger = require('./logger');
```

My question is, is it possible to use nodejs like this?

Comment: you can try component: https://github.com/component/component

Comment: you can try browserify if your want to use npm modules: http://browserify.org/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Node.js` is a serverside application where you run javascript on the server. What you want to do is use the `require` function on the client.

Your best bet is to just write the `require` method yourself or use any of the other implementations that use a different syntax like [requireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/).

Having done a bit of extra research it seems that no-one has written a require module using the commonJS syntax for the client. I will end up writing my own in the near future, I recommend you do the same.

[Edit]

One important side effect is that the `require` function is synchronous and thus loading large blocks of javascript will block the browser completely. This is almost always an unwanted side-effect. You need to know what you're doing if you're going to do this.  The requireJS syntax is set up so that it can be done asynchronously.

Comment: Ah that's a pity, I really liked the syntax of nodejs, requireJS seems to be more verbose

Comment: @dfuse I'll see if I can move the write `require.js` for client-side coding higher up my to do list. I'll let you know once I've written it.

Comment: hmm your remark about synchronisity will make me get a second look at requireJS

Comment: @dfuse I plan to preload all the scripts I need and write my own `require.ready` block. Then you can just use your code as normal except it only runs in the `onready` block.

Comment: guess @Raynos never did it... :(

Comment: @Kayvar it's hard to do the impossible... ;-)

Comment: @inf3rno looks like it! That's ok I worked around it :D

Comment: If you&amp;#39;re interested, Chromium based browsers allow you to use  `import` by specifying `type=&amp;quot;module&amp;quot;` on the script tag loading the main script. `<script type="module" src="/JS/index.js";></script>`

Answer (score 40):

SubStack on github has a module called [node-browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify).

It will compress and bundle your modules and deliver it as a single js file, but you use it just like Node.js (example from module readme):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/browserify.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var foo = require('./foo');

        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = foo(100);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    foo = <span style='font-family: monospace' id="result"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

From the module description:

> **Browserify**
>
> Browser-side require() for your node modules and npm packages**
>
> Browserify bundles everything ahead-of-time at the mount point you specify. None of this ajaxy module loading business.
>
> More features:
>
> - recursively bundle dependencies of npm modules
> - uses es5-shim for browsers that suck
> - filters for {min,ugl}ification
> - coffee script works too!

Comment: I've used Browserify for a while now. What a headache... try Head JS

Comment: @BMiner, You should add that as a separate answer. So folks can vote up/down.

Comment: @marcello are you sure this is how Browserify works? From my reading you can't just add a `<script>` tag with the library prior to your other code... you have to write the code requiring the node modules as a `main.js` and then run a command-line `browserify main.js -o bundle.js` to bundle `main.js` with all of its `require` dependencies into a `bundle.js` file. I cannot find a working example using the pattern provided in your code sample. If I'm wrong can you please point me to a link?

Answer (score 20):

[Browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify) magically lets you do that.

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer is correct when it comes to RequireJS. But, fast-forward to 2020 and we now have [ES modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) pretty much on every browser except IE <= 11.

So, to answer your question "how to use node.js module system on the clientside". Let's start with the fact that you could leverage ES modules already, e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Hello 2020</title>
  <!-- load the app as a module, also use defer to execute last -->
  <script type="module" src="./app.js"></script>
</head>

<html lang="en">
  <body>
      <div id="app">
          <h1>Demo</h1>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
import { hello } from './utils.js'

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {           
    document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerText = hello('world');
});
```

util.js

```
function hello(text) {
    return `$hello {text}`;
}

export { hello };
```

Now let's assume you want to use an npm package in your browser (assuming this package can run on both browser and node). In that case, you may want to check out
[Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/posts/2020-05-26-snowpack-2-0-release/).

> Snowpack 2.0 is a build system designed for this new era of web
> development. Snowpack removes the bundler from your dev environment,
> leveraging native ES Module (ESM) support to serve built files
> directly to the browser

In other words, you can use npm packages thus allowing you to use the "node module system" in your client application.

Answer (score 9):

## Webpack

I would recommend [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) which automates node module loading, dependencies, minification, and much more.

### Installation

To use node modules in your project, first install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) on your machine. The package management system [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) should be installed along the way. If you have already installed node.js, **update Node.js and NPM to the latest version**.

### Usage

#### Initialization

Open your project in your code editor and inititialize npm by typing `npm init -y` to the command line. Next, install webpack locally by typing `npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev`. (`--save-dev` means these dependencies are added to the `devDependencies` section of your `package.json` file which are not required for production)

#### Reorder Folder Structure

Follow the tree structure below to reconstruct your project folder:

```
yourProjectName
  |- package.json
  |- /dist
    |- index.html
  |- /src
    |- index.js
```

Create a `dist` folder to hold all distribution files and move `index.html` to that folder. Next, create a `src` folder for all source files and move your js file to that folder. You should use the **exact same file and folder names** as appeared in the tree structure. (these are the default of Webpack but you can configure them later by editing `webpack.config.js`)

#### Refactor dependencies

Remove all `<script>` importations in `index.html` and add `<script src="main.js"></script>` before the `</body>` tag. To import other node modules, add [import statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) at the beginning of your `index.js` file. For example, if you want to import `lodash`, just type `import _ from 'lodash';` and proceed to use the `_` in your `index.js` file.

**NOTE**: Don't forget to first install the node package first before importing it in JS. To install `lodash` locally, type `npm install lodash`. Lodash will be automatically saved to your production dependencies in `package.json`

#### Run Webpack

Finally, run webpack by typing `npx webpack` in your command line. You should see `main.js` generated in the `dist` folder for you by Webpack.

#### Additional resources

The above guide provides only the most basic way to use Webpack. To explore more useful use cases, go to the [official tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) of Webpack. It provides extremely comprehensive tutorials on topics such as asset management, output management, guides for development and production, etc.

#### Reference

https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

Comment: It doesn’t look like it will work if we import ‘fs’ module, and use fs to read a file using ‘fs.readFileSync’

Comment: @PraveerKumar I find that the package `fs` is not currently in use from npm. For getting started with module loading, I recommend you check out [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard/recent) which completely automates module bundling for npm modules, React, Vue, Angular, Gatsby, etc. It actually uses VC Code in the browser and features hot reloading and code collaboration. I found it particularly useful for testing out new modules and APIs.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to write code for browser with same style modules as you do for Node.js, try [Webmake](https://github.com/medikoo/modules-webmake). Take a look also at simple prototype of application build that way: [SoundCloud Playlist Manager](https://github.com/medikoo/soundcloud-playlist-manager)

Comment: nice! It's your own project I see?

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as logger from '/node_modules/logger/logger.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good require node.js-like library for client side. It's called wrapup. Check it out [kamicane/wrapup](https://github.com/kamicane/wrapup)