# making relative url absolute using arbitrary root in javascript

Tags: javascript, url

Assuming that I'm on a page on a different domain (mydomain.com) and that the relative url only exists in code (not in the DOM)

How do I combine two arbitrary urls entirely in javascript?

```
var a = 'http://example.com/some/path/';
var b = '../other/path/';
var c = magicUrlCombine(a,b);
assert(c == 'http://example.com/some/other/path/');
```

It should also work for

```
var a = 'http://example.com/some/path/';
var b = 'http://pink-unicorns.com/some/other/path/';
var c = magicUrlCombine(a,b);
assert(c == 'http://pink-unicorns.com/some/other/path/');
```

**EDIT:**

I'm looking for a completely general function for combining an absolute url with an arbitrary url. The same logic as the browser uses for resolving links but for urls that are not in the HTML of the page and/or not relative to the current location.href.

```
var a = 'http://example.com/a/b/c/';
var b = '../d/e/';
assert(c == 'http://example.com/a/b/d/e/')
```

OR

```
var b = '/f/g/';
assert(c == 'http://example.com/f/g/')
```

OR

```
var b = 'http://jquery.com/h/i/';
assert(c == 'http://jquery.com/h/i/')
```

**EDIT 2:**

node.js has a [url module](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/url.html) that has the right functionality, but I haven't found a nice way of reusing it on the client side. ([how to use node.js module system on the clientside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944863/how-to-use-node-js-module-system-on-the-clientside))

I managed to hack my way through making it work but it's not really a solution I feel comfortable putting into a production site. [Hackety hack](http://jsfiddle.net/jesperll/wtbb5/9/)

Comment: For clarification I'm looking for the equivalent of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay1kx93s.aspx


a is absolute, b is absolute or relative, c is absolute.

Comment: can you please update your example with real examples where there is no repeat paths in the base and relative? Perhaps my answer is still correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JQuery Mobile has it**

[$.mobile.path.makeUrlAbsolute(relPath, absPath)](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html)

```
console.log($.mobile.path.makeUrlAbsolute('../d/e/', 'http://example.com/a/b/c/'));
console.log($.mobile.path.makeUrlAbsolute('/f/g/', 'http://example.com/a/b/c/'));
console.log($.mobile.path.makeUrlAbsolute('http://jquery.com/h/i/', 'http://example.com/a/b/c/'));
```

all give the expected results

Answer (score 2):

I have used on the server side, using NodeJS,

```
var url = require('url');
url.resolve(from, to);
```

in your case:

```
var a = 'http://example.com/some/path/';
var b = '../other/path/';
var c = url.resolve(a, b);
assert(c == 'http://example.com/some/other/path/');

var a = 'http://example.com/some/path/';
var b = 'http://pink-unicorns.com/some/other/path/';
var c = url.resolve(a, b);
assert(c == 'http://pink-unicorns.com/some/other/path/');
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't resist having a go at a solution

```
var magicUrlCombine = function(a,b){
   return (a + b).replace(/[\w\-\.]+\/..\/|\:\/\/[\w\-\.\/]+http/g,'');
}
```

works for both test cases and combinations of the two

http://jsfiddle.net/8HLeQ/2/

Comment: Might work in narrow cases, *not* a general solution. Fails for any URLs with 2-char path elements (you didn't escape the '..'). Also fails for servers on custom ports, https, and the simple case when you are redirecting from 'path/start.html' to 'finish.html'. But nice try :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible, but untested, solution:

```
function magicCombine(a,b){
    if(b.indexOf('://') != -1) return b;

    var backs = 0;
    var lastIndex = b.indexOf('../');

    while(lastIndex != -1){
        backs++;
        lastIndex = b.indexOf('../', lastIndex+3);
    }

    var URL = a.split('/');
    //Remove last part of URL array, which is always either the file name or [BLANK]
    URL.splice(URL.length-1, 1)

    if(b.substr(0,1) == '/')
        b = b.substr(1);
    var toAdd = b.split('/');

    for(var i = 0, c = toAdd.length-backs; i < c; ++i){
        if(i < backs)
            URL[URL.length - (backs-i)] = toAdd[backs+i];
        else
            URL.push(toAdd[backs+i]);
    }

    return URL.join('/');
}
```

Should take care of both cases...

Comment: Hmm, why should `magicCombine('http://example.com/a/b/c','../d/e/f')` become `http://example.com/a/d/e/f`? `../` is only "one dir up", afaik..

Comment: Because c is not a dir (no final slash). The dir is b. One dir up is then a/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6WycA/7/ Again, updated.. Hadn't taken into account, that c would be the filename, and c/ would leave a blank space in my array...

Answer (score 1):

I assumed I understood the question but my fiddle returns two false. The examples are not obvious

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/z5SUn/

```
function magicUrlCombine(a,b) {
  var linkA = document.createElement('a');
  linkA.href = a;
  var linkB = document.createElement('a');
  linkB.href = b;
  return linkB.href.replace(linkB.host,linkA.host)
}
```

Comment: this only (sorta) works if the links are relative to the current page. I'm looking for a completely generic solution

Comment: @Jesper -  that sounds like you need FreakTM's solution instead