# How do I reference a js file from a node module in HTML?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, webstorm

I've used JetBrains WebStorm to create a Node.js Express App.  I used npm (via File->Settings->Node.js and NPM) to install a package called [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) which is used for string validation.

The package was installed under **node_modules**, which is fine.  If I do `var validator = require('validator');` in my server code, I can use the validation functions successfully.

The problem is that I would also like to use validator in client JavaScript.  I can include the script like this:

```
<script src="/javascripts/xss-filters.min.js"></script>
```

But that means I have to copy **xss-filters.min.js** from the **node_modules** folder into the public **javascripts** folder.  Then, if I ever update the package with npm, the files will be out of sync.

Is there some way to reference **node_modules** from my view, or to create some sort of linked file or file reference or something?  I'd rather not have to maintain this manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should consider using browserify, which allows you to require modules in the browser by building all the dependencies. so basically you code like you would do in server side http://browserify.org

Comment: I appreciate this is a very old question / answer - but I'm trying to get my head around this. Without browserify, all node_modules need to be referenced in script tags in the HTML? Surely when NPM updates a package, the script path is then broken?

Comment: i installed browserify  but for me require() is still not working! do i have to add something in my code to use browserify?

Answer (score 1):

You can done it by using another node.js module, called [node-browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)

- [how to use node.js module system on the clientside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5051800/2896595)

You can try to use [bower](http://bower.io/%22Bower%22), or [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/%22yeoman%22). 
bower - will simplify the process to include js libs.
yeoman - will help you to build projects with the the libraries that you need.