# How do I use javascript require?

Tags: javascript

I have spent a day trying to figure this out. Given my js knowledge is dated I end up sorting out a moshpit of 'new' technologies where every doc and author expects you to know these things. It all creates one big brainfog. So I ask if anyone can explain how i enable require and Request in the code Im trying out.

To be specific, I have a working php API on my server using Hawk HTTP authentication. I am trying out the example javascript from the Github repo.

https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk

**Client Code:**

```
const Request = require('request');
const Hawk = require('hawk');


// Client credentials

const credentials = {
    id: 'dh37fgj492je',
    key: 'werxhqb98rpaxn39848xrunpaw3489ruxnpa98w4rxn',
    algorithm: 'sha256'
}

// Request options

const requestOptions = {
    uri: 'http://example.com:8000/resource/1?b=1&a=2',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {}
};

// Generate Authorization request header

const header = Hawk.client.header('http://example.com:8000/resource/1?b=1&a=2', 'GET', { credentials: credentials, ext: 'some-app-data' });
requestOptions.headers.Authorization = header.field;

// Send authenticated request

Request(requestOptions, function (error, response, body) {

    // Authenticate the server's response

    const isValid = Hawk.client.authenticate(response, credentials, header.artifacts, { payload: body });

    // Output results

    console.log(`${response.statusCode}: ${body}` + (isValid ? ' (valid)' : ' (invalid)'));
});
```

**Error**

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

I can relate to that this would cause an error when require is not part of plain javascript. What will i need to understand/learn/implement to make this work? Note that this is all on the client side.

Comment: You need a module bundler, like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript require() function giving ReferenceError: require is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: require() is not part of your standard JavaScript. In context to your question and tags, require() is built into Node.js to load modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module you are looking at is designed to run under [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/) (which has native support for `require`) and not in a browser.

You *might* be able to get it to [run in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944863/how-to-use-node-js-module-system-on-the-clientside), but it is likely that you **cannot** due to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) *and* **should not** because it would leak your credentials to anyone who visits your website.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So a code for the client that is supposed to be run on a server... Don't make sense to me :)

Comment: @wyldcard — Don't conflate "NodeJS" with "Server". NodeJS is simply a way to run JavaScript programs. You can write client software in it. (And a single piece of software can be both a client and a server: A proxy server is a common example, it lists for requests from HTTP clients but then makes HTTP requests to other HTTP servers to get the data to give to the client).

Comment: I accepted you answer and I understand. I did try it but I abandoned Hawk and went for JWT instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`require` is part of the [node API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules) and is not available in the browser. In order to use modules in the browser, you will need to run your code through a bundler such as [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org) first.

Be aware that there are still some modules (such as `fs`) which cannot run in the browser due to the way they interact with the system (i.e. reading a file from disk). I believe `request` falls in that same category.

I recommend you use Browserify to start out, due to its simplicity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will read up on browserify and have a go at it.