# try to update the text in a LABEL with OBSERVABLE but don't work

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I follow a lesson on nativescript and want to update the text in a LABEL (xml) with OBSERVABLE but my app crash.

xml:

```
<Page loaded = "mypageloaded">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button text="TAP" tap="onButtonTap" />
        <Label id = "lblcounter"  text="{{mylabel}}" />
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

js:

```
var observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");

var counter = 42;
var page;

var user = new observableModule.fromObject({
  mylabel: "Test observable"
});

exports.mypageloaded = function (args) {
  page = args.objects;
  page.bindingContext = user;
};

exports.onButtonTap = function () {
  counter--;
  console.log(counter);
}
```

if I put the line PAGE.BINDINGCONTEXT in comment, no crash...and no update...

Comment: `require` is a nodejs specific thing and is not natively supported in a web browser. You can read for alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4944920/3729184)

Answer (score 0):

It's typo, `page = args.objects;` suppose to be `page = args.object;`.

`args` is typeof [EventData](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/interfaces/_data_observable_.eventdata).

Comment: Thanks Manoj. I had also to change the LABEL for TEXTFIELD in my xlm file.

Comment: I don't know why you did that, may be if you wanted editable input. But it has nothing to do with crash or exception.