# Using NodeJS module in Moodle

Tags: node.js, moodle

I'm trying to use a NodeJS module for development of Moodle plugin. I've installed the module by **npm install** command and now it in the **node_modules** folder. I know that for using it in my script I have to define it in AMD style, like:

`define(['jquery'], function($) {`

Please advise how can I define it.

Comment: `jQuery` is not `Node.js` specific - you could always just use a `CDN` to import `jQuery` in your page instead.

Comment: I need a NodeJS module to be imported, jquery just an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use node.js module system on the clientside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944863/how-to-use-node-js-module-system-on-the-clientside)

Comment: @goto1 nope, that doesn't solving it unfortunately

Comment: Hello Nikita Lvov, do you find the solution ? I am having the same issue.