# Writing JS code for both browser and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, browser-console

Being relatively new to programming in general, the code I usually write in JS isn't very complex. I have never felt the need to segment it into smaller chunks that would be easier to manage, until now.
I would always use the approach of using a single file with a single object

```js
const mymodule = {
    feature: function(){...},
    submodule: {
        property: 5,
        ...
    }
}
```

I would then simply load it in html. For debugging I used the browser console.
But recently I've installed nodeJS and learned about the system of modules and I thought that was exactly what I need for my current project. So far I coded it using the technique shown above, but that is now hard to manage. Scrolling through one giant messy js file is quite frustrating. I also realized that maybe I'd like to use this project in node as well, so modules would really help I thought.

On [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) I learned that modules can also be used in the browser, which made me very happy, until I realized that in the browser they cannot be run locally, but rather only through http(s) - served (meaning I cannot use my favourite chrome console for debugging ). But if the module system is the same as in nodeJS, than I could use node to still run and test the project locally!

However, I can't figure out how I could work with modules so that they could be used both in the browser and in node. For example the confusing ways of requiring, importing and exporting (`export` x `exports =`  x `module.exports =` ).
I am aware of [some older questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944863/how-to-use-node-js-module-system-on-the-clientside) similar to mine, but they are very old. Since modules are now literally a part of web standarts, I really hoped there would be a simple way to do this without the need for any external tools.

If you can point me in the right direction or show an example of writing a module that can run in both enviroments, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use web bundlers for this case.
Something like snowpack will allow you to use nodejs modules that locally installed by running `snowpack dev`. It will provide you local web server and opens browser window with your page automaticly, that also allows you to use MDN examples.

Comment: yes, i found rollup to be the easiest one to learn. thanks!