How to set up a VS Code project that includes referenced JavaScript npm modules
I have a web project that uses TypeScript and I'm able to easily import, see and use npm modules, but when I load the web page in the browser the npm modules are not found.
My VS Code project is set up like so:
/mypage.html
/myproject.ts (my typescript)
/myproject.js (javascript created by typescript)
/tsconfig.json
/.vscode/tasks.json

If I reference a library in my TS file and view it in the browser it can't find that module or gives other errors. See below.
But if I manually go into the npm module and dig around and find the library.js file and then copy that to a folder in the root directory then the web page in the browser can see and use that library. This works but by manually copying the library into the main source directory I'm losing many of the benefits of npm.
I believe if I can define an export directory for all the web page files I can have my TypeScript files copied to it, my HTML pages copied to it and npm modules copied to it, then I believe it will work when run in the browser. It seems it should work this way?
Is there a way to do this? Is there a way to do this with tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json? Is there a webconfig.json or vscodeconfig.json that will copy all files in a directory to another directory (including referenced npm modules)?
I have a Node.js Express project that uses TypeScript and any imported libraries just work. I don't have to do anything to get it to work (tsconfig.json maybe). I want that same thing for my client side TypeScript that compiles to JavaScript used in web pages project.
I feel like this should be basic 101 web development (and it works to a point) but I can't seem to find a way to get it to integrate the npm modules in the output.
Note: Suggestions have been pointing to using bundler. I've started down this path but still learning. See below.

More info:
I'm using a local server (http://localhost) to load the web page (there are plugins for vscode) in the browser. I have a separate project that is a nodejs project that starts a nodejs server, also running localhost.
TS to JS is converted by settings in the tsconfig file. I have file watcher on so that saving typescript files creates the js files.
I'm not using webpack or any other bundler and many have been suggested. I'm not against it only I haven't found a guide yet and some are confusing. Most guides I found are how to setup a React or Next js project. I want to setup a vanilla js project. A few projects like Snowpack or Vite look like what I want but I can't tell if it's a plugin for vscode or a vscode replacement (it looks like a replacement). Some of them seem to run in the browser.
I've also just read about import maps. This looks helpful because it can point to the npm modules on a remote site if they exist already. But I don't know how it will work locally. I will try to see if I can get import maps working.
I want to use this module in my web projects. Specifically BaseClass.ts.

Web Project Example
My basic web project that that is related to this question is here. It is all setup and working except for the issue mentioned in this post (the module is not rolled up, bundled or exported or included when typescript is compiled or when the page is viewed in the browser).
I just updated the npm package (1.0.2) to include Javascript files. I had only had Typescript files before. Not sure if it helps.

.vscode/tasks:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "option": "watch",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc-watch"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "label": "tsc: watch - tsconfig.json"
        }
    ]
}


tsconfig.json (suggestions welcome!)
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,  
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}

With the tsconfig settings I have above I get errors and the library is not found.
script.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at script.js:2:23


The source tab shows only the script.js file is included (the npm module is not found or included):

HTML:  (simplified)
<script type="module">
import {BaseClass} from "base-class-ts"

export class MyClass extends BaseClass {

    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("Hello world")
    }
}

BaseClass.startWhenReady(MyClass);
</script>

If you are working on an answer for the bounty and using a bundler, please add how to support source maps (if possible).

This is already a long post but I'm putting some things I find here (rather than in a comment or an answer) and no I haven't tried them all I'm still figuring this out too:

Using import maps to access the node module:
https://youtube.com/watch?v=En1lSiMjLvU

After updating the npm package and other things I have things partially working in the test project here. Probably some bad practices in there. Going to work on adding a bundler to the mix next.



Couple of questions for clarity... are you using an HTTP server at all; how are you loading the web page in your browser, via http://... or file:///...? What is your build process (to convert TS to JS) and are you using a bundler like Webpack, Vite, Rollup, etc?

Maybe you are looking for importmaps, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62106568/65694

"I feel like this should be basic 101 web development" - it is, yes. What you're describing is a bundler, like Webpack or (as you've already been told) Vite.

According to your question you can't tell the difference between a text editor, a text editor plugin, and a Javascript bundler? Is that really the case? Or is that part worded poorly? "Most guides I found were how to set up a React or Next.js project" again, really? What about those? Glancing at your other questions on this, to answer your meta question, no, there is no real way to do what you want. Yes, it's dumb that there...

...is no easy solution for this and bundlers are required. It still is what it is, and you still have to use them (the alternatives are generally worse, which is why everyone is telling you to bundle).

@JaredSmith of course I can tell the difference. but my question was referring to doing this in vscode. and someone suggested vite without many details about it "Use Vite". OK I look it up, "Vite- Next Generation Frontend Tooling - Get ready for a development environment that can finally catch up with you."

@JaredSmith It also seems that if I use a bundler I lose source maps in the browser. I hope that's not the case. So, this an many other errors are the reason behind this post. I'm following along a guide on webpack now.

@1.21gigawatts no you don't lose source maps, just have the bundler generate them. Secondly, yeah, that seems like an unfortunate word choice on the vite homepage. Vite is a bundler/task runner, like webpack. The problem that I have with this question, and by extension your other questions, is that it isn't clear what it would take to answer it: how much of modern webdev do we need to explain? All of it? Too long. Some of it? Ok, which parts? Don't get me wrong, much of it is non-obvious. I get that it's confusing (especially with marketing bs). I just don't think we can answer it here.

@JaredSmith I want to get the project I have mentioned running and working in the browser. It's a web page accessing a module and importing a npm module and supports typescript. As I've worked on this over the last few months I've encountered error after error. I've also discovered that things don't work without the project layout being setup in a specific way and without config files setup in a certain way. You can take the project, modify and get it to work or create one separately, or show what needs to change to get this to work (posting details in an answer).

All the little details take time. Getting an import to work, getting typescript config correct, getting tasks config correct, getting, webpack config correct, getting  npm config correct, etc. Hopefully someone has figured this out already and knows how to get it working. I haven't found that yet. My client side typescript javascript projects work (sort of) but I have to copy in the npm modules js file into the output directories manually for it to work.

Also note I'd look up one bundler then it's say to use another bundler. Then I'd find out that it's no longer maintained, "Update (April 20, 2022): Snowpack is no longer actively maintained and is not recommended for new projects." It was a rabbit hole. But I have sort of got import maps pointing to a node module (moment - see video link in post) and that's now loading in the browser...but it's not working with my library. It's one thing after another. And it seems with import maps I still have to use a bundler or link to a cdn or remote domain.

Try not to get confused between a "development environment" and an "integrated development environment (IDE)". The former is the system and tools you use to do local development (your PC, terminal and CLI utilities). The latter is, to put it very simply, a fancy text editor

@1.21gigawatts again, that's a rant (a fully justified and relatable rant, but a rant nonetheless) not a question. A question is "how do I configure vite or webpack so I don't have to manually copy dependencies from node_modules?". I realize this is more complicated than say, your typical Python project, but people going through bootcamps manage this task every day. If your real question is "this can't really be this hard can it?" then the answer is simultaneously yes (it's way harder than it should be coming from a saner ecosystem) and no (it's still totally doable for a 17k rep SO user).

@JaredSmith If import maps can't do what I want and a bundler is needed then I understand your point. You want me to be more specific. I'm still reading up on things. If import maps work (the reading sort of does but the bundling doesn't seem to) then the question would be fine if I rewrote it as you suggested, "How do I configure vite or webpack so I don't have to manually copy dependencies from node_modules?" But import maps sort of solve the reference part so I don't want to rule that option out yet. If someone wrote an answer, "Not possible yet" I accept those answers.

@JaredSmith People don't seem to want to write an answer, "You can't do that yet" or "no it's not possible" but I don't mind those as answers. You could put your comments into an answer. Someone might come along trying to do the same thing and your comments would describe to them, "here are the options you have right now".

"If I reference a library in my TS file and view it in the browser it can't find that module or gives other errors." - how did you configure your web server to serve the files that you installed into the node_modules  folder? "I want to use this module in my web projects" - if you want to use ES modules (given the import declaration in the <script type="module"> in your html) and modern async/await syntax, you should use neither "target": "es2016" nor "module": "commonjs"  in your tsconfig.json.

"I just updated the npm package (1.0.2) to include Javascript files." - no you didn't. You updated the github repo, but you didn't publish a new version to npm yet. Btw you should normally not commit the JavaScript files to git, they are considered build artifacts. You should version only the TypeScript sources (and the build scripts).

@1.21gigawatts Robert Sandiford's answer is a pretty good summary of the concerns and available options after the edit a few hours ago.

@Bergi "how did you configure your web server to serve the files that you installed into the node_modules folder?" I don't know that's something I could do. I created the example project on github so anyone can see how far I've got and see what else might need to be done.

@gigawatts uh you said it's a web project so I assumed you are serving these files (at the least the index.html and presumably the script.js) on the web. You do use a web server, no? Then how did you configure it? There's nothing in your repo about that.

@Bergi he says somewhere that he uses a VS Code extension. In my answer I used the "live-server" extension to mimic his setup.

@Bergi I use Live Server https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer.

@1.21gigawatts Sorry I can't help with that, and its documentation is sparse. And you'll need to think about where to host your files anyway if you want to develop a web site.

@Bergi I have Live Server working. The issues I have are the ones mentioned in the main post.

After all the updates and changes I have a test project that is partially working here https://github.com/velara3/WebAppTest. It references the js files from the Typescript classes. It would fail on the production server unless those Typescript classes are published with everything else. Going to go through the answers describing using a bundler.

I don't know how to award the bounty. These are all helpful answers. The answer with bun works (don't know how to get source maps). I haven't been able to try vite yet as I run out of time. The bounty expires tomorrow (will try to test the vite answer). If I could split the bounty I would.

Update III to my answer with bun includes screenshot and howto for source maps of your package base-class-ts (as well as working repo): https://stackoverflow.com/a/78640115/117030

Possibly someone from this post is posting spam to the webapptest repository https://github.com/velara3/WebAppTest/pull/1#issuecomment-2234497995. User live-os. or vortex. It's going on daily. I can't find the comment to who first posted the fork


TypeScript can compile your code to a variety of formats, but usually it will either be ECMAScript Module format (ESM) or the CommonJS format (CJS).
ESM looks like import foo from 'foo' while CJS looks like const foo = require('foo').

When you import or require 'foo', there is a resolution step to decide where to look for the module foo. Import resolution for code running in node.js is different to resolution in the browser. For this reason code written in the node.js style typically does not work in the browser as-is. NPM is a package manager for Node, so this system should be expected to work in Node but not in the browser.

Modern browsers support ESM modules, although the import resolution will differ, but they don't support CJS modules. We can therefore make some progress by ensuring that we compile to ESM modules with TypeScript. It is possible then to translate the imports to the correct locations with an import map - the problem here is that an import mapping is required for every incompatible import reference, and it can be difficult to identify all of those, and even then they are likely to change as you develop.

For a production application is has been popular to transpile code into older more widely supported JavaScript, and use a bundler to combine the code into 1 or more large bundles, that use more primitive JavaScript features to emulate modules, without relying on any module format. It's debatable whether this is still necessary - TypeScript alone can handle transpiling to early forms of JavaScript, and caniuse.com says that ESM modules are supported by 97% of browsers in use, so it is possible today to use ESM modules for a final application, which could be exactly the same as the development setup.

Ultimately, and perhaps you don't want to hear this, but converting from the NPM/node_modules format to a browser suitable format is a non-trivial task, and its best done by an existing build process. Vite is probably the fastest way to get started with a vanilla JavaScript project that can you npm modules (Get Started with Vite). Vite is a development server and build tool that runs from the command line. They provide a command line tool to create an empty project that is setup to use Vite.

If you want this to be any simpler, then the answer is not to use npm, but instead to use a system that is web compatible. For example, CDNs provide links that you can insert straight into a web page. There may be a package manager out that there that works like npm, but designed for the browser exclusively, but if so I don't know it - to be frank in the JavaScript world often we have really become quite dependant on build tools, that can sometimes be quite complex, so the quick answer to doing things the conventional way is to use the existing tools or frameworks rather than try to recreate it.



I'll give a slightly more direct answer of how to do what is requested - but then I'll talk about why this is probably NOT what you should do (although it does contain various information that may be helpful to people).
A) Using the sample project https://github.com/velara3/WebAppExample as of 2014/06/19.
B) The package 'base-class-ts' is not correctly structured, so instead we'll use Luxon, a date-time library for our project. install luxon and install -D @types/luxon (vary depending on package manager). script.ts is changed to
import { DateTime } from "luxon"
const now = DateTime.now()
document.getElementById('date')!.innerText = now.toLocaleString()

and index.html has <div id="date"></div> inserted at line 17 after <h1>Hello World</h1>.
C) We're going to set TypeScript to use Node import resolution and compile our code as ESM. To do this in tsconfig.json we set "module": "NodeNext", and do not set "moduleResolution" - "moduleResolution" will be automatically set to "NodeNext" due to the "module" setting. These settings are telling TS to use Node import resolution, and to decide on whether to compile to CJS or ESM depending on the Node settings. To set Node to ESM mode in package.json we add "type": "module". TS will recognise this and now write ES modules.
D) Compile the TypeScript code with tsc.
E) In index.html add an import map in the head:
  <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "luxon": "/node_modules/luxon/build/es6/luxon.js"
      }
    }
  </script>

How do we know the target to map to? In this case it was just investigation of the luxon package. It could also be determined from the luxon package.json (although in this instance the package.json "browser" field suggests "build/browser-cjs/luxon.js", which does not seem suitable, I instead picked the ESM file.
F) Serve the project and view the index.html page. Per the OP's setup I am using a VS Code extension (live-server) to serve the folder locally.
Result: You should see a web page with "Hello World" and then the current date below.

Now, why is this NOT the correct answer? (Taking the core of the question to be "How do I create a TypeScript web project that can use npm modules?")
i) You cannot use a CJS module from npm in this way. This system relies on ESM modules, and a package that is published only in CJS cannot be used. CJS modules are more compatible than ESM modules within Node itself (it is difficult to load asynchronous ESM modules in Node projects using synchronous CJS modules), so this is still common.
ii) Finding the correct file to map the import is not always trivial. Node has a relatively complex import mapping system allowing for import location rewrites. We also need to consider that some packages provide different files for the browser and account for this, and any other issues that may pop up.
iii) What if we import 'luxon/foo.js'? Well this is now a separate import location, so we need a separate entry for this in the import map. As far as I know there is no wildcard support in import maps suggestion here.
iv) A module in a package can import another module in the same package using a bare import (e.g. a luxon file could write import 'luxon/lib.js'). You must provide an import mapping for this import too.
v) Imports to other dependencies from a package, such as a luxon file importing 'helpers' require an import mapping provided manually by you.
vi) If you update your dependencies and their structure or dependencies change, then again, you need to update your import map to work.
If all of your dependencies are ESM, and you complete all of the above steps, then yes you can make this work for a development environment. Now lets consider to want to push this code to production:
vii) Accessing files over the web is slow, loading files, checking their imports, loading their imports, and waiting for each one to load across  the web is very slow. For good performance over the web small files need to be bundled together. This requires a bundler. So for production you are now going to need to configure a bundler, and discard your import mapping. So after all of the above, you'll need to almost start over and do a new, separate setup to make it work well on the web.
A tool like vite on the other hand handles all of this - converting modules into usable formats for local development, import resolution, serving local files, and building for production (using a bundler called rollup).

See my other answer for a practical solution using Vite.

This is a great explanation. I wish I had read this a year ago. It sounds like I need to use a bundler like Vite and see if by following those guides it will import my library. It also sounds like this area of web development has one foot in the past and one foot in the future (and not all the past development and tools and libraries are compatible with the future toolset yet.

Originally JavaScript had no module system, everything was in the same global space, and 2 scripts that declared the same variable would conflict. Node.js, which is for running JavaScript via command line, was built around the CommonJS system, which wrapped each file in a function to isolate it and provided functions for loading one module from another. That was not available on the web hence needing build tools. Node also had a unique resolution scheme. Then in ECMAScript 2015 (the JS standard) they introduced official modules (ESM), but yeah we are now left with a bit of a mix of systems.

I think the hypothetical solution here would be to use ES Modules and to use a resolution system that is compatible between Node (or other JS runtime) and the web. Perhaps we would use import '/node_modules/base-class-ts', which would just require that the server serves those files at the same location as they are in the project. But also serving many files is much easier locally than over the web, if there are many small dependencies then this generally requires compacting them into bundles, and its not clear how that would happen with a pure npm style package system.

The current tools, such as Vite, do work well. It is just a shame that we need so much heavy lifting (even if it is done for us) to make a simple project using this system.

By the way 1.1. gigawatts, if you want/need a guide on how to do this in Vite, I could provide that in a separate question. I don't really think it is correct to give a vite guide in response to this question, because the question is not specific to Vite, and there are many ways to do it. Vite is probably the go to option. But I think a "How do I set up a project in Vite" question the more appropriate place for such a guide. But perhaps that is not needed.

Great! I just somehow got it running in the browser locally here https://github.com/velara3/WebAppTest. It still has some of the issues you mentioned and they are valid. I didn't try your import suggestion in your second comment. That might solve some issues. Adding the node_modules folder to the server might solve some issues but obviously may be a bad idea? Going to try with a bundler next.

The import style there was hypothetical in the sense that it is not supported in Node, that would require new standards, or some Node-side import mapping. Note: vite is not a bundler, it's a development server. It effectively automates all the stuff you're doing now + handles converting CJS modules, and perhaps some other details. Building for production in vite uses a bundler (rollup).

I ran the vite template example and got it working in the browser. It has a lot of stuff in the web developer source view I'm still going through. It ran it's own server. Will this output html that I can run with node js

Update:
Solution with Bun bundler

Bun is an alternative to NPM package manager with TS built in.
Bun is also a bundler.
Since Bun understands TS files, there is no need to have JS files in your base-class-ts package
Bun is also an alternative to the Node.js runtime, but we are only using the bundler (and package manager) for this solution.
Some other TS-aware alternatives:

JSR
Deno



Detailed steps:

Install bun
Clone your project: git clone https://github.com/velara3/WebAppTest.git; cd WebAppTest
bun install (instead of npm install, which may also work)
bun add -d bun-plugin-html (Add plugin so Bun can bundle index.html files.)
bun bun.build.js (See contents of file below)
Use server of choice to serve contents of output in /build/ directory

// bun.build.js

import html from 'bun-plugin-html';

await Bun.build({
  entrypoints: ['./public/index.html'],
  outdir: './build',  // Specify the output directory
  plugins: [
    html()
  ],
});





Updates II & III were removed and posted as part of new answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78664790/117030
It turns out my server was serving the unbundled files (not the build directory...)


Original Answer before update
You seem to want to use NPM to manage TS packages in the browser.

Node Package Manager was not designed with the browser in mind; it was made for server-side Node.js applications.
In addition, both NPM and the browser were designed for JS; not TS.

So you are fighting  at least two uphill battles, especially if one of your goals is to avoid JS bundlers (one of your best allies in this battle). While it is possible and similar things have been accomplished before, you are trying to use and combine tools in ways that were not originally intended.
Also note even if you get your package working as a JS module from NPM, a lot of TS information is stripped when compiling to JS. So there may be limitations with importing a base class and extending it like in your script.js.

Having said that, I will try to offer some specific advice:
First, I suggest... [see answer history for original text]

"I suggest getting the package you wish to import working in a Node environment" - actually I disagree with that. It's a package written for a browser environment, using document and other DOM stuff. You'll never get it working properly in node. Admittedly, getting the module imports working correctly (with "type": "module" in the package.json etc) with node's module resolution (via node_modules) is a good first step, but ultimately doesn't help with the actual goal. My upvote counts only for your first paragraph :-)

"Node Package Manager was not designed with the browser in mind; it was made for server-side Node.js applications." Indeed. That's where I was having problem after problem. Typescript and nodejs and npm worked great for nodejs server side but as soon as I targeted the browser side and client side JS I had lots of problems. It doesn't seem to be impossible because I have most of it working roughly in another project but I have to manually copy any libraries, the minified js, I use and it has to be setup up a certain way and it's not doing everything the server side has working out of the box

"You seem to want to use NPM to manage TS packages in the browser....also note even if you get your package working as a JS module from NPM, a lot of TS information is stripped when compiling to JS." yes exactly. if I link to the JS it's compiled down mess. If I link to the Typescript it shows the full class but there are other issues that happen (like that Typescript class needs to also be compiled to JS and compiled into the main js file used by the webpage).

I'll try pointing main to the js file and see if that works and see if I can publish the js to npm (although it's suggested not to it may help temporarily with testing).

I updated the npm and pointed to a index.ts file that includes three exports. I published that 1.0.4 and then went through every tsconfig module option and checked the browser for errors and the console in vscode for typescript errors. All of them gave typescript errors or browser errors except one. If I have "target": "ESNext" and "module": "Preserve" I get a readable ES output to JS and no errors in the terminal from Typescript. Updated the import maps. I get errors in the browser the files are not found in node_modules. Seems maybe the library or project is further along with these changes

If the server could see the node_modules folder this might work. But it seems the server is not seeing it. And obviously I don't want all of the node_modules only the ones referenced.  http://localhost/node_modules/base-class-ts/BaseClass net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found). The import map:
{ "imports": { "base-class-ts" : "../node_modules/base-class-ts", "base-class-ts" : "../node_modules/base-class-ts/index.js" } }

AHHHH I sort of got it working in the browser!! Import map:  "base-class-ts/" : "../node_modules/base-class-ts/". Module import:
import {BaseClass} from "base-class-ts/BaseClass.js" Its' finding the class in vscode and linking to it (javascript version), it's running in the browser showing source code. This won't work on a production server because those node_modules won't be there. But seems to point to Typescript files when in vscode (clicking on class name)

Also, I've updated the project WebAppTest https://github.com/velara3/WebAppTest. It should be working as much as described.

@1.21gigawatts I updated my answer with a simple solution using Bun.

How is performance using bun to bundle, especially updating the bundle during development and as the project grows? Bundling in development feels obsolete to me, compared to using modules + automation, but then I haven't tried it since the painful days of doing this with webpack, and I haven't used bun either (mainly due to allegations of bugs that still need to be ironed out).

@RobertSandiford Bun touts speed as one of its advantages over node.js. OP's sample project was almost instantaneously bundled. I normally use SvelteKit (vite), which uses esbuild to incrementally bundle during dev and rollup to build for production. Recently I have tried experimenting with SvelteKit + bun: as long as you don't use any bun-specific features, it is simple to fall back to more stable tools. Bun may be a little faster, but I haven't noticed any major difference either way.

Yeah I can imagine such a small project would be fast. But in the webpack days startup time for a react app could be around 1 minute, and update time 1-2 seconds. I'm sure this is much better, but I'm still curious how it goes when you get to a typical project size with some large dependencies, and then into some really big project sizes. (With modules performance should be pretty much constant at any size, because only that module needs to update.)

@RobertSandiford Here's a comment from 3 years ago: went from 10 min build with rollup to 0.25 second build with esbuild. Full discussion. Some more discussion. Personally, even my most complex SvelteKit projects update instantly, and startup takes a few seconds at most.

Seems viable then, maybe not at the mega scale, but for us ordinary coder types. Don't suppose it would be hard to migrate if it didn't become a problem one day.

There were a few reasons I was avoiding bundlers. Possible performance degradation as the project grew and the loss of source maps for debugging. If all the files are bundled up then how can one debug the code in the browser? But someone said you can retain source maps with some settings. It also sounds like vite solved the issue with performance by using esmodules.

@1.21gigawatts I updated with details about debugging with no-config source maps and addressed performance concerns.

@Leftium great update! I was looking at the merge request and I'm going to create another project repository for bun with your changes

@Leftium vscode wants me to install DevContainer extension from MS?

@Leftium so I accidently learned docker (or part of it). does bun need docker? can those be removed?

@Leftium I went through steps 1-6 and it created the build folder and that works but it might not be working as we want. If I go to http://localhost/build/public/index.html it only shows the TS file. If go to http://localhost/public/index.html it shows the ts files but I believe that works because it is picking up the public directory not the build directory. If I change the name of the text on the page in the /public/index.html it shows it's loading two different pages. But this may be a server issue. I select the page and run Live Server.

Continued... it might be working based on import maps. But the files in the build folder don't show the source maps. That might be less of an issue if things work in the end.

It might be the build folder is causing the import maps to fail. In your screenshot the import map shows the node modules folder. To see if bun works we would need to remove the import maps and I'd need to be able to run my server the same as yours because the /build/public path gets different pages than the /public path in the url

@Leftium I removed the import map, ran bun, and launched the page  and it doesn't show the TS files and I believe that's because they aren't referenced anywhere. The index.js file has all the classes inside it and there are no import maps so it doesn't show them. Breakpoints work inside the file. I'll ask a separate question on getting the source maps to work in bun. It does swap the slash type in the module path. <script type="module" src="../src\index.js">. I believe the issues I have now might have to do with how the server is setup.

Setting sourcemap: "inline", in the bun build file sort of works. It is pointing to the JS. Bun also seems to have a publicPath folder that might solve somethings. I'll commit what I have in the repository. I committed some changes and they appeared on the fork. https://github.com/Live-os/WebAppTest

@1.21gigawatts I have added a final update with additional screenshot, explanation, and GitHub repo. I don't think there is much more I can do beyond this~

Thank you. I will check it out. How are you launching the server? I click on /build/public/index.html and click Go Live (vscode extension). I also tried /public/index.html and click Go Live. I think you are viewing the original html page and not the bundled HTML page. Maybe that's fine for development? If I debug the page locally what do I use? The bundled page? It seems I may need to always have import maps to get the source code to work - to show the TS classes. Try removing the import map and see what happens.

Also, I had to award the bounty. If you want I can create another question, "How to import the npm library in bun" and award the bounty on that question.

I'll add that question separately and post it back here when it's ready

@1.21gigawatts You're right: I thought I was serving the build directory, but it turns out I was serving the original files from the root directory. I updated this answer and added another answer explaining how to start the server where source maps work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78664790/117030

@Leftium Thank you for this guide. Also, been getting spam on the project. I don't know who's account it is but if you made a branch you might want to check your account is ok.  http://www.github.com/velara3/WebAppTest/pull/1#issuecomment-2234497995. User live-os. or vortex.

Here's a guide to doing this using Vite.
I'll create a new project, because I think this will be more useful to most readers and generally more appropriate. I'll use the "luxon" package, because the provided package is invalid, and fixing that would distract from answering this qustion.
This assumes that you have node and pnpm installed.

Create a folder

In that folder, run pnpm create vite .. Choose a package name. Choose "Vanilla". Choose "TypeScript".

Install initial dependencies with pnpm i

Install new dependencies pnpm i luxon and pnpm i -D @types/luxon

Replace the code in src/main.ts with


import './style.css'
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>('#app')!.innerHTML = DateTime.now().toLocaleString()


Run pnpm dev

Control+click on the local server location, e.g. "http://localhost:1234/" to open the site in a browser.

You should see the current date in the middle of a web page.

To deploy to production, run pnpm build, then take the files from the dist folder and serve these to the web however you choose (ordinary simple file hosting or an express server should both be viable choices).



I can't find pnpm. I tried to install it with npm i pnpm and it installs something but when I call pnpm create vite . it says command not found.

I also tried npm install -g @pnpm/exe from https://pnpm.io/installation I think it works but could I also use $ npm create vite@latest? It shows the same prompts (from https://vitejs.dev/guide/). pnpm is opening a separate terminal window. Is there a way to do this without @pnpn/exe?

I ran the vite template example and got it working in the browser. It has a lot of stuff in the web developer source view I'm still going through. It ran it's own server. I'll try and go through the steps without pnpm and only use npm and then see if I can view the page in the browser. My project uses nodejs server so I don't know if I can switch

npm and pnpm should be largely the same, with npm being slower. The output of Vite is a simple set static web files that can hosted with any simple web server, including express, apache, nginx or Amazon S3. You can create a sister express app and use something like const app = express(); app.use(express.static('../website/dist')) to serve the files with express. The sister app is assumed to be outside of the vite app, but sitting in the same parent folder, and the vite app to be in a folder called website.

To debug with source maps from node_modules folder:
Using any web server, like BrowserSync


git clone https://github.com/Leftium/WebAppTest.git The git repo is a fork of the OP repo with some minor changes:

Unneeded stuff removed.
Browsersync server added.


npm run browser-sync Start server and open in browser.
Open devtools to source tab and browse to node_modules/base-class-ts/BaseClass.js
Click "Configure" next to the warning "This script is on the debugger's ignore list."
Uncheck the custom exclusion rule that starts with /node_modules/ This rule was preventing your library from loading source maps. However, this will probably cause all NPM packages to load source maps.
Reload the page.
Open devtools to source tab and browse to node_modules/base-class-ts/BaseClass.ts. Set a breakpoint.
Reload the page.


Why this works:

The server is serving JS files with source maps to the TS files.
I think any server should work, but I added browser-sync so everything is consistent for everyone.
No bundlers were involved, but bundling may be done separately for deployment to production environments.


Before adding a tutorial "how to use BrowerSync", it would be good to start with "What is BrowserSync and what do I need it for?". Because neither in your answer nor in their documentation I can find what it really does nor what this has to do with setting up a web project with npm dependencies in VS code.

@Bergi BrowserSync is jus a web server; any web server should work so I de-emphasized BrowserSync.

Oh, it's a web server? I wouldn't have guessed that. From their description, it looks more like a browser extension… "Browsersync makes your browser testing workflow faster by synchronising URLs, interactions and code changes across multiple devices." Maybe it does that by having a builtin webserver so one doesn't need to install a custom browser extension into every browser to test, but still serving web pages seems to be far from its primary purpose.

@Bergi Browsersync injects a script into the served pages so it can automatically reload when the server detects file changes. I just (occasionally) use it because it is simple to start serving any directory with a single CLI command; no installation/configuration. There are probably a lot of features I've never even used.
